# 500 (Internal Server Error) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to allow a person to remove items from their cart using jQuery and AJAX. Whenever I click the link to remove an item I get a 500 internal server error. Here is my code:

```
@model AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.OrderDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/Orders/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<h3>
    <em>Review</em> your cart:
</h3>
@*<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout
>>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
</p>*@
<div id="update-message">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Product Name
        </th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>
            Price (each)
        </th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.ProductId">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Product.ProductName, "Details", "Products", new { id = item.ProductId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                @item.ProductPrice
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="item-count-@item.ProductQuantity">
                @item.ProductQuantity
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.ProductId">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.OrderTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the remove method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
{
    // Remove the item from the cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    // Get the name of the product to display confirmation
    string productName = db.OrderItems
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.ProductId == id).Product.ProductName;

    // Remove from cart
    int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

    // Display the confirmation message
    var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
    {
        Message = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) +
            " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
        CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
        CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
        ItemCount = itemCount,
        DeleteId = id
    };
    return Json(results);
}
```

Here is the code for the **RemoveFromCart** referenced in the previous method:

```
public int RemoveFromCart(int id)
{
    // Get the cart
    var cartItem = entities.Orders.FirstOrDefault(
        c => c.OrderGUID == ShoppingCartId
        && c.OrderItems.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault().ProductId == id);

    int itemCount = 0;
    int? cartItemConut = cartItem.OrderItems.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault().ProductQuantity;
    if (cartItem != null)
    {
        if (cartItemConut > 1)
        {
            cartItemConut--;
            itemCount = (int)cartItemConut;
        }
        else
        {
            OrderItem oi = cartItem.OrderItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            entities.OrderItems.Remove(oi);
        }
        // Save changes
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    return itemCount;
}
```

Here is the code for **ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels
{
    public class ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
        public int CartCount { get; set; }
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }
        public int DeleteId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more

Comment: check the console (f12) on the request and let us know, this is server side anyway (permissions )

Comment: All it says is 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console

Comment: You really need to look at your server-side logs.

Comment: @jmar777 where are the server side logs?

Comment: depends what web server you're running i will assume IIS(just an assumption ) so check the event log! Your WebServer logs is what you're looking for anyway !

Comment: 500 is almost always because your controller method is throwing and exception. You need to show your controller method. You can also check the details using your browser tools (inspect the Network tab)

Comment: Side note: `if (recordToDelete != '')` should not be necessary (based on your `foreach` loop, it should never be an empty string

Comment: In the console (F12), click on the Network tab, then right click on the link with the 500 error, and select 'Open link in new tab'. You will see what error has been thrown by the Controller.

Comment: I got rid of the internal server error, but it's not acting just right, if the quantity is 1 it removes it just fine, but if it's more than 1 it says it removed it but it doesnt

Comment: @PsychoCoder, Then you need to show your code

Comment: If you attach to the server, you can debug it and find out what exactly the error is. However, I can tell that `string productName = db.OrderItems
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.ProductId == id).Product.ProductName;` will error if the id doesn't exist. Default is likely `null`, and `null`.Product = error.

Comment: @PsychoCoder, You need to debug you code. Put a break point on the first line of code and step through it to determine which line of code throws the exception. You have a number of lines that could cause a problem such as `FirstOrDefault(item => item.ProductId == id).Product.ProductName;` and `FirstOrDefault().ProductQuantity` - `FirstOrDefault()` can return `null` and trying to access a property of null throws an exception.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have stepped through the code, the 500 error was due to permissions, which I resolved. What I'm trying to resolve now is it wont remove something from the cart if it has a quantity greater than 1

Comment: That's a different question, so you need to ask a new one (and either delete this one or add your own answer to this one showing how you solved it, and accept it so its not left in the unanswered queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission error, went in and gave the ASPNET account permissions on the controllers folder and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

500 server error means that there was a exception in your code. I'm guessing from your code that cartitem or oi(orderitem) was null and you were trying to do a LINQ query to those. Check first are they null before trying to do query.